# Three simultaneous calls causes process spikes to 25% per call

Tags: nginx, flask, uwsgi

to present my configuration I followed this tutorial until "Securing the application"
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uswgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04#step-4-%E2%80%94-configuring-uwsgi
So my .ini looks like this:

```
[uwsgi]
module = wsgi:app

master = true
processes = 5

socket = myproject.sock
chmod-socket = 660
vacuum = true

die-on-term = true
```

In flask i'm using SQLAlchemy with this configuration:

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_COMMIT_ON_TEARDOWN'] = True
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_POOL_RECYCLE'] = 299
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_POOL_TIMEOUT'] = 20
```

My api endpoints are like this with various themes, they receive parameters via get, process, and return a json

```
@app.route('/api/theme1/subtheme1')
@auth.login_required
def get_test1(): ...

@app.route('/api/theme1/subtheme2')
@auth.login_required
def get_test2(): ...

@app.route('/api/theme1/subtheme3')
@auth.login_required
def get_test3(): ...
```

Now my problem, when, for example I make 3 simultaneous calls (not other calls to the api) to those 3 endpoints procesor of the uwsgi process spikes to 25% per call.
Im using a tiny compute engine, just running this for now, the ram is for another tests. n1-highmem-2 (2 vCPUs, 13 GB memory)

I googled and search here and even tunning a little the configuration cannot reduce the processor usage, so I cannot improve the overall performance of the API.

Any idea of what can I be doing wrong? Why the spike in cpu usage?
Thank you!

Comment: I can think of 2 things. It could be an issue with whats in your `get_test\d()` functions or have you tried playing with the number of processes you are running?

Comment: The local response is really fast (running flask standalone), it gets 3 fields from a table with 1 record, simple as that, then converts it to json and return data.
It now uses 25% processor in each one of the three calls, if I lower it below 3 it will take longer I think, If I raise more than 5 it will have less processor to do the work...what logic should I use to adjust that value? Thanks!

Comment: It’s just trial and error testing for things like this. Though you may want to check to make sure you don’t have debugging turned on. I have seen reports of this kind of issue around it.

Comment: I'm about to try with gunicorn, but will very much like to learn what's happening here, thanks!

Comment: Alejandro -- After looking at flask-httpauth source code, I think you should try removing @auth.login_required from each of those routes and try it again. If not, then I'm stumped. As a side note to the earlier comments, the general rule for number of processors is processors =  (2 * CPU Cores) + 1.

Comment: @brannon if I remove that line the client will connect without autentication. Not possible. Thanks!

Comment: @Alejandro I'm trying to see if it is possibly due to using an inefficient hashing algorithm. There should be a way to change the hashing algorithm to hex_md5. For example, when using flask-security, the following config settings improve the speed of my authentication greatly.
```python
app.config["SECURITY_HASHING_SCHEMES"] = ["hex_md5"]
app.config["SECURITY_DEPRECATED_HASHING_SCHEMES"] = []
```

Comment: Now I understand your point, I'll try it as soon as I can. I'll be printing some timestamps too. Thank you